# jQuery validate (at least one field has text)

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have this page which has several TextAreas (asp.net mvc).
I need to validate that at least one of those fields has text in it.
How can I do that with jQuery?

```
<%= Html.TextArea("taMetodologia",Model.Enmienda.Detalles.EnmiendaMetodologia, 8, 70,new {@class = "Especificaciones"}) %>
```

That's an example of the textAreas I have.

Comment: If you are using a more recent version of ASP.NET, you may want to look into validation via the ASP framework. Includes both server and client-side validation and is simple to use (via Data Annotations). http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are not using the validate plugin and all the textareas have the "Especificaciones" class, you could use a filter on the class.

If the length of the following is greater than 0, then at least one of the textareas had a value in it.

```
$(".Especificaciones").filter(function(){
    return $(this).val() != "";
}).length;
```

Comment: this was exactly what i needed, something simple and easy to implement, thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Check out this link as it should be what your looking for:

[jQuery validation: Indicate that at least one element in a group is required](http://rmurphey.com/blog/2009/04/15/jquery-validation-indicate-that-at-least-one-element-in-a-group-is-required/)

Quoted from the above link:

To start with, I put class="required_group" on each of the elements in the group. Then, I added a custom validation method:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('required_group', function(val, el) {
    var $module = $(el).parents('div.panel');
    return $module.find('.required_group:filled').length;
});
```

... a custom class rule to take advantage of the new method:

```
jQuery.validator.addClassRules('required_group', {
    'required_group' : true
});
```

... and finally a custom message for the new method:

```
jQuery.validator.messages.required_group = 'Please fill out at least one of these fields.';
```

---

Here is another link to someone that used this method but tweaked it:

[jquery validation only one field in a group required](http://www.dixis.com/?p=101)

Comment: @Kelsey: This makes several error messages.. How can I display only one?