# jQuery Validate plugin. How to check if any of fields is filled in

Tags: jquery-validate

How to check if any of 4 fields I have is filled in? If any of them is filled in, then it's fine, if not, it's not.

Comment: This [blog post](http://blog.rebeccamurphey.com/2009/04/15/jquery-validation-indicate-that-at-least-one-element-in-a-group-is-required) may help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery validate (at least one field has text)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678401/jquery-validate-at-least-one-field-has-text)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#sendMsg").click(function(){
  var name = $("#name").val();
  var email = $("#email").val();
  var subject = $("#subject").val();
  var message = $("#message").val();

  if(name == ""){
    $("#errorMsg").show();
    return false;
  }

  if(email == ""){
    $("#errorMsg").show();
    return false;
  }

  if(subject == ""){
    $("#errorMsg2").show();
    return false;
  }

  if(message == ""){
    $("#errorMsg3").show();
    return false;
  }

});
```

Comment: wow thats allot of code I'm sure this could be written much better but since itsa a dup  there is not point

Comment: This is only sipmle example to understand of how you can done it :)

Answer (score -1):

`if (document.getElementById("idfield1") === undefined)
{
    // do noting 
}
else
{
    // do something 
}`