# How to display only one error message when at least one field is required and all are missed?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I use [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3678493/604388) to ask user to input at least one value into group of fields.
But in case user inputs nothing in all fields, then error message is shown for **all** empty fields. How can I show it just for one field? or separately? 
I was trying to use [errorContainer option](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions), but it affects other fields.

Comment: could use errorLabelContainer , puts all errors in one container, set your css to only show 1st child (untested)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a loop around all the elements. Find the one that's empty.

```
$('form input').each(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == ""){
        //do code
    }
});
```

That should work. Try and see. :)

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to do that with jQuery validate - so error messages and according fields will be well formated, error field focused etc. - don't want to do all this staff manually.